# Normalization in vector field in QFT after non-relativistic expansion

Tags: electromagnetism, wavefunction, schroedinger-equation, qft-in-curved-spacetime, normalization

I encountered this equation when I was reading the article "[Black Hole Superradiance Signatures of Ultralight Vectors](https://arxiv.org/abs/1704.05081)"

$$A_\mu=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2m}}\Big(\psi_\mu (\vec{r})\exp(-i\omega t)+\mathrm{c.c.}\Big),$$
where $A$ is a vector field in QFT, and $m$ is the mass of the vector boson. This is a non-relativistic expansion. $A$ itself satisfies the Proca equation of motion and Lorenz gauge,
$$D_\mu F^{\mu\nu}=mA^{\nu}$$
$$D_\mu A^\mu=0.$$
Where $D$ is the covariant derivative in the Kerr geometry. But to the leading order, it is just the derivative in the flat spacetime.

The above expansion will result in $\psi$ satisfying a Schrödinger-like equation. My question is that how is the normalization of $\psi$ determined in this case?
Should each component of $\psi$ integrate to 1? Or should $|\psi_x|^2+|\psi_y|^2+|\psi_z|^2$ integrate to 1?

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/599857/2451