# Is it that radiation and electron exhibit dual nature in certain situations?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, spectroscopy

“Whenever radiation interacts with matter, it displays particle like properties in contrast to wavelike properties, which it exhibit when it propagates.”

Does it mean at certain situations radiation have particle like and at certain situation wave like properties. Does it also apply to electron?

I am not getting the exact meaning of this statement .

Comment: Where did you find this statement , it is not universally true

Comment: It is in my textbook ma’am .@trula . NCERT class 11chemsitry.pg44 to be precise.

Comment: Wikipedia: [Wave—particle duality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wave–particle_duality)

Comment: Have a look at my answer here and the link there https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/627025/i-understand-what-it-represents-but-what-physically-is-the-wave-function/627049#627049

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your textbook should give you examples  where you observe wavelike behavior, so called interference experiments and particlelike behavior like in the photo effect. But the statement you quote is to general to be true. If its not to high for you  read the article in wikipedia  G. Smith mentioned to you